# How do you use this function from amazons ProxyConfiguration class?

Tags: java, proxy

I'm trying to understand how to use the below function and it just isn't making sense to me. It comes from the software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ProxyConfiguration import. My understanding is that this function gets called when you want to set the endpoint for a proxy. If that is the case then why does it check for an empty path (the proxy you wish to use) and throw an error if one exists?

```java
@Override
public Builder endpoint(URI endpoint) {
    if (endpoint != null) {
        Validate.isTrue(isEmpty(endpoint.getUserInfo()), "Proxy endpoint user info is not supported.");
        Validate.isTrue(isEmpty(endpoint.getPath()), "Proxy endpoint path is not supported.");
        Validate.isTrue(isEmpty(endpoint.getQuery()), "Proxy endpoint query is not supported.");
        Validate.isTrue(isEmpty(endpoint.getFragment()), "Proxy endpoint fragment is not supported.");
    }

    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    return this;
}
```

This is how I am currently using the function. s3ProxyConfig is just an object that stores the 3 pieces of data being used.

```java
ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = ProxyConfiguration.builder()
        .endpoint(URI.create(s3ProxyConfig.proxyEndpoint()))
        .username(s3ProxyConfig.proxyUsername())
        .password(s3ProxyConfig.proxyPassword())
        .build();

    return ApacheHttpClient.builder()
        .proxyConfiguration(proxyConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some creative use of the URI object I am able to pass a Url to the endpoint function and everything works correctly.